# Javascript get url without querystring

Tags: javascript

I have the following url:

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?new=question'
```

How would I get the url without the querystring? Right, now I am doing the following, but is there a single method to do this instead of adding two?

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get all the different parts of a url, `location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname` would be the correct syntax. Here's an example displaying the url where this snippet is hosted:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "The snippet is at this web address: " + getURL();

function getURL() {
  return location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For example like this - `location.href.split("?")[0]` - split by `?` and take the first element of the resultant array. It will work even if there is no `?` in location - the whole url will be the single element of array.

ps: downvoter - comments? don't be a chicken.